# Algorithm for calculating most efficient grouping

Tags: algorithm

I have quite a strange question on my hands.

I have a list (~500 entries) of lengths of wooden beams in different sizes, such as 3400mm, 1245mm, 900mm, etc.
The maximum length of a wooden beam is 5400mm and in order to reduce the amount of wood being wasted I want to find an algorithm that tries every possible way to combine the smaller sizes to fit into 5400mm beams or as close as possible.

So let's say I have five different lengths: 3000, 1000, 300, 2000, 900 I would end up with:

- 3000+2000+300 = 5300 // The closest combination to 5400, meaning the amount of wood being wasted is only 100mm on this beam.
- 1000+900 = 1900 // The rest

I'm not sure if this qualifies for the traveling salesman problem and I have only begun to imagine what the algorithm might look like. But since there are so many smart people with combinatory skills here I just wanted to throw it out there before I bang my head bloody.

**To make things even worse**

Let's say we do find a solution to the problem above. The guys over at the wood shop rarely delivers 5400mm beams but it can range from 3000 to 5000 in 100mm intervals.
So I'll get a list of beam lengths from them on delivery.

Would it be possible to match the list "this is the beams I got" with the list "find out the best combination of the required beam lengths"?

I'm not sure if it's worth it in the end but any help is appreciated.

Kind regards
Richard

Comment: Doesn't sound exactly like TSP, but does sound like it's probably NP-complete (just much closer to a subset-sum problem).

Comment: It's a 1D cutting stock problem. Linear programming with column generation works well. The variant can be handled by adding some constraints to the LP.

Comment: It sounds vaguely like the knapsack problem, but only vaguely.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Cutting Stock Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) in 1 dimension.  It's reducible to the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) so it is in fact NP-complete, but it's generally tractable and in cases where it isn't many good approximate solutions exist, because this is an insanely important problem in industry.

It's typically solved exactly using dynamic programming, which is kind of a mindfuck, but you can find plenty of example implementations to help you out.  Approximate polynomial time solutions typically call the dynamic programming code (which has pseudo-polynomial complexity) at various points, and the surrounding code is simpler.  I guess the take home message here is don't try to write it yourself, find someone else's code and port it to your language and application environment.